# Self-signed certificate for Client

Tags: ssl, https, ssl-certificate

I'm confused on how Self-signed certificate works.

Our application will connect to a server to get some info via SSL or https. This mean we are the client. The server is asking us to provide the Self-signed certificate. I created a RSA Key pair and a self-signed certificate.. What cert or key will provide to them? The public key and the self-signed certificate? and do we expect certificate from them?

Answer (score 1):

> What cert or key will provide to them?

Only the self-signed certificate should be provided. The private key should be kept private (hence the name).

> ... and do we expect certificate from them?

This depends if they also use self-signed certificates at their end or if a publicly trusted CA has issued the certificate. In the first case they need to provide the certificate, in the latter case your client just needs to trust the common publicly trusted CA (i.e. what the browsers do).